# How to Intercept and cancel method execution

Tags: c#, unity-container, interceptor, aop

Is there a way to *intercept* a method execution and **cancel** it? 
I've only found a way to do it throwing an exception from the `Invoke` method using `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` and `ICallHandler`, but on the `Invoke` method implementation, I can only return `getNext()(input, getNext);`.

Bassically this is the code:

```
public class TestHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, 
                                GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's been intercepted.");

        // Here... please Lord, tell me I can cancel it, I'm a good person.
        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that Lord won't help you, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @downvoter comment your downvote. You might don't know the answer, it's ok, but the question is pretty good and you know it.

Comment: why do you want to cancel the execution? where is your method running(i mean is it on same thread)? give us more details please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by cancelling. The client code has invoked the method and it expects a result or an exception.

What you can do is avoid calling the original method in your handler, effectively stopping the pipeline, but you need to do something to complete the method call.

To bypass the rest of the pipeline, which includes the original method, you need to create a new method return with the CreateMethodReturn method in the IMethodInvocation interface for a successful return or with the CreateExceptionMethodReturn method for throwing an exception. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650526(v=pandp.20) for details.

For example instead of doing

```
return getNext()(input, getNext);
```

you could do

```
return input.CreateMethodReturn(null, input.Arguments)
```

to return null.

For a general purpose handler, you'd need to analyze the intercepted method signature to figure out what needs to be returned.

Comment: And that's what I was just looking for, why on earth did I missed that `CreateMethodReturn` on my reasearch! Thanks dude! You rock!

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend to look at AOP approach. For example PostSharp.
They have a lot of aspects for different use cases.
Details here:
http://www.sharpcrafters.com
You can take a look for MethodInterceptionAspect

Comment: Actually, this is AOP too, but thanks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx